# use matplotlib legend with lmplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

```
g = sns.lmplot(x='x', y='y', df, fit_reg=False, hue='z', lowess=True, scatter_kws={'alpha': 0.5}, legend=True)
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.01, 0.5), ncol=2)
```

In the code above, if I set `legend=True`, I get both the default single column seaborn legend and the matplotlib legend. If I set `legend=False', then I get neither. How do I draw only the matplotlib 2 column legend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access the `legend` property via `g.ax`:

```
# example data
N = 100
data = {"x":np.random.random(N),
        "y":np.random.random(N),
        "z":np.random.choice([0,1], size=N)}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

g = sns.lmplot(x='x', y='y', data=df, fit_reg=False, hue='z', 
               lowess=True, scatter_kws={'alpha': 0.5}, legend=False)
g.ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.01, 0.5), ncol=2)
```

[image: scatter plot]